# Django map Urls

Tags: python, django, url

Hello I am new to django,

I have created a simple app for category wise product. for that I wanted to display as below url patterns.

- / -> Home page
- /product  -> category page
- /product/product_name -> product page

to achieve this I have wrote a below code.
`myapp/urls.py` file

```
import product

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^manage/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include(product.urls)),
    url(r'^product/', include(product.urls)),
]
```

in `myapp/product/urls.py` (I am managing app wise urls)

```
from views import product_name, product_root

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', product_root, name="ProductRoot"),
    url(r'^product_name/', product_name, name="ProductName"),
]
```

Now when I runs the app and browse the page it gives me below result.

- / -> product category page
- /product -> product category page
- /product/product_name -> product category page **(but it should be product page)**
- /product/product_name/any_value -> product category page **(Should return 404)**

Can anyone guide me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to terminate the patterns in your app urls:

```
url(r'^$', product_root, name="ProductRoot"),
url(r'^product_name/$', product_name, name="ProductName"),
```

Otherwise the first one will match everything.

Comment: No, you explicitly must *not* terminate the URLs in the main file that include other files.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri The `$` marks the *end* of the URL: if you are including new patterns you don't want to end it.

Comment: Ohh Yes. I miss interpreted your comment. You are correct in that case it should not be ended up with `$`